# The polynomial ring over a (non integral) ring is not a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to prove that if $R$ is not a field, then $R[x]$ is not a PID. I can prove the proposition, assuming that $R$ is a commutative unitary ring and an integral domain, but I cannot prove it without assuming that $R$ is an integral domain.

The way I want to prove this, is by looking at the ideal generated by an element $a \in R$ that is not a unit (and $a \neq 0$),and by $x$. So I looked at the ideal $(a,x)$, which is basically just $$\{a_0a + \sum_{i=1}^{n_a}(a_ia)x^i+ \sum_{i = 1}^{n_b}b_ix^i\ |\ a_i,b_i \in R\}$$

Obviously $1 \not \in (a,x)$, but $x \in (a,x)$. So if I take any element $c \in R[x]$, I have the following cases:

1. If $c$ is a unit in $R[x]$ then obviously $1\in (c)$, so $(a,x)$ cannot be generated by $c$
2. If $c$ is not a unit in $R[x]$, but constant, then $x\not \in (c)$, since we would have to find an element $r \in R $ with $cr = 1$.
3. If $c$ is not a unit in $R[x]$ and not constant: Here is what I struggle with. For integral domains $R$ I can show that $x \not \in (c)$ or $a \not \in (c)$, since multiplying two polynomials (by definition) would give me the equalities $r_0c_0 = 0$ and $r_0c_1+r_1c_0 = 1$ for $c = \sum_{i = 0}^m c_ix^i$ and $r_i \in R$. Then using the definition of an integral domain, I would get $r_0 = 0$ or $c_0 = 0$. If $r_0 = 0$ I get a contradiction since $c_0$ cannot be a unit in $R$ if $c$ is not a unit in $R[x]$. If $c_0 = 0$ then obviously $r_0c_0 \neq a$ so $a \not \in (c)$

How can I generalise my prove to general unitary commutative rings?

Comment: If $R$ is not an integral domain, then $R[x]$ isn't a [**P**rincipal **I**deal] **D**omain either.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path You are right... This question is basically nonsense then. Thank you very much! I am learning this in german and the name we have for principal ideal domains does not imply that $R$ has to be an integral domain, but I looked up the definitions and just realised that mistake.

Comment: Yes, in English the more general notion goes by the name "principal ideal *ring*".

Comment: This paper I think will be of interest to you: https://msp.org/pjm/1968/25-3/pjm-v25-n3-p11-s.pdf